# Alt Gr+M doesn't produce the left angle bracket (<) anymore. What can be done?

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout

I tried to implement the `left Ctrl` `+` `left Alt` from [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/157815/868361), but it didn't help me.

I'm using Windows 11 Pro with Hungarian keyboard layout on laptop.

Every key depicted on the keyboard works, except for this (`<`).

**EDIT**: The left side of the keyboard to produce the `<` with `Alt Gr` + `í` works, but the `M` should work as well since it has an "engraved" `<` on it, too. It is the second, next to the `.` button, next to the right `Shift` (obviously the letter **M**). The `.` + `Alt Gr` also gives `>`, which works, only the one mentioned key-combination doesn't.

Image of the keyboard:

[image: My keyboard in question]

**2nd EDIT**:

Important to know is that the key-combination worked on a previous Windows 11 installation on the same current machine in question. Currently when I press the `M` together with `Alt Gr` it produces nothing.

Comment: I have no problem with a Windows 11 VM using the OnScreen Keyboard : AltGr+í gives `<` and AltGr+y gives `>`. Test your keyboard when booting in Safe mode to see if the problem is due to some installed product.

Comment: Do I understand right that the problem is only with one key on your keyboard that Windows 11 doesn't recognize? What character does this key generate in Windows 11? Could you add a link to your keyboard layout so that I can see it visually and does this keyboard have a name?

Comment: What does this key produce when clicked with AltGr?

Comment: @harrymc It produces nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean installation of the Windows 11 fixed the problem.

Now I can type/produce the < with both the M and Í buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows 11 does not fully understand your keyboard, I can offer
a solution for this one missing key that uses the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
to the character `<` (but you could use instead any other
key-combination that you prefer):

```
<^>!m::Send, <
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I won't want to install a third party app. Even though this might fix the problem, is there a solution that would be to add some kind of registry entry that would do the same? **Important:** the key combination worked before on this operating system.

Comment: No, the built-in keyboard mapping via the Windows registry does not handle key-combinations, only single keys. AHK is one of my best utilities, which I use for many purposes (not chiefly for key mapping).

Comment: With what can you explain that the key combination did produce the desired character once before the last installation of the Windows 11 on the same machine in question?

Comment: Perhaps errors by Microsoft developers? You may signal the problem to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bountie for your answer, because it's relevant to my question. Thank you for your time and effort in this. :-)

Comment: Thank you - upvoted your post and answer, so have 20 rep back.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me, it occurred after installing Geforce Experience.

It bound `Ctr+Alt+m` to the microphone mute. After I removed this bind, the `AltGr+m` shortcut is working again.